# Reducing height of "footer-widget-container" (currently 182px)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'd like to reduce the current height of 182px of my **'footer-widget-container'** (I'm using Wordpress theme Press Coders).

However, I can't find the relevant file to edit 
(have tried footer.php, black.css and style.css, anyone know which file I need to edit?

Please see the site at:

```
http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/
```

Comment: Seriously?? Do you think we can help when we have no code to see??

Comment: Oh crumbs! Please see the site at:

    http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this  to your style.css file

```
.footer-widget-container {
          height: 125px;
      }
```

what height you want to just change it.

Answer (score 0):

Your css code for Footer is in **Style.ccs.**

Open it and find

```
.footer-widget-container {
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

And then just adjust height

```
.footer-widget-container {
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
height:200px; /***Your Desired Height**/
}
```